# Instagram Real Time API OAuth limit exceeded

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I'm trying to set up a subscription and just created an account and client a few minutes ago. When I try to send the POST request using PHP and cURL, I get this error:

```
{
 "code":429,
 "error_type":"OAuthRateLimitException",
 "error_message":"You have exceeded the maximum number of requests per hour. You have performed a total of 5476 requests in the last hour. Our general maximum limit is set at 5000 requests per hour."
}
```

I don't think it's even possible to have sent this many requests in the time I've had my account much less in the past hour. Is there any other reason Instagram would return this error?

Here's the code I'm using. It's one page to handle both the initial cURL request and the return request.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['hub.challenge'])) {
  $curl_handle = curl_init('https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/');

  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    client_id => CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret => CLIENT_SECRET,
    object => 'tag',
    object_id => 'kitten',
    aspect => 'media',
    callback_url => CALLBACK_URL
  ));


echo curl_exec($curl_handle);

} else { 
  echo $_GET['hub.challenge'];
}
?>
```

Comment: It could be indicative of a bug in your code.  Perhaps you are sending thousands of requests when you think you are only sending one.

Comment: I agree with @dubstylee - please post your code so we can see whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of experience with the Instagram API, and I'll tell you that they are very rarely wrong. The fact that your error has 5476 requests tells me that they are not wrong in your case either. At 5000 requests, Instagram automatically generates the 429 response, meaning from the time you hit 5000 requests to the time the 429 response was triggered, generated and pushed back, you had made an additional 476 requests. This sounds about right, in my experience, as this is all happening virtually instantaneously.

Furthermore, when this happens, it can take quite a bit of time for Instagram to accept ANY API requests from that particular account or Client ID. When this happens I just remove the old app from Instagram developer, and create a new one that is really the same just with a different Client ID and secret.

From the code you have posted, it looks like you're recursively asking Instagram to search for media with #kitten. Your if and else statement both make the same request ultimately, and for whatever reason are creating an infinite loop of requests.

That's all I can tell you from what you've posted - if you can provide the code where you implement the Instagram API (i.e. CLIENT_ID, CALLBACK_URL, CLIENT_SECRET...obviously I don't need the actual info, just need to see how and where it's implemented), then I'm sure I could figure it out for you.

Comment: Should I just set up the subscription using a command line cURL request? It seems that you are right and there is a loop of requests. I have not yet implemented how I'm handling subscriptions. The code I posted is everything I currently have. I just want to set up the subscription right now.

Comment: You need to add in some sort of kill switch after the first request returns JSON. are you receiving the JSON? If so, how are you handling it. Seeing that code might provide some insight. Once you get a response - 200, 400 or otherwise - you need to add a method to kill the request. Something like curl_close($curl_handle) should work.